# fill data automatically in a relationship table

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm developing a spring boot application which creates student accounts for a given student. The structure has a one to many relationship table created by the annotations. Now, every time I create a new student account, the `student_id` and `student_account_id` must be saved ***(automatically)*** in this relationship table which only contains the `student_id` and `student_account_id` as **foreign keys**. I don't know how to achieve that. Here's the code:

**Student class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "student_id")
    private int studentId;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(name = "relationship_table",
               joinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_account_id"))
    private StudentAccount studentAccount;
```

**StudentAccount class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student_account")
public class StudentAccount implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "student_account_id", nullable = false)
private int studentAccountId;
@Column(name = "username")
private String username;
@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "relationship_table",
           joinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name = "student_account_id"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"))
private Collection<Student> students;
```

***Edit:***
Here is how I build the student_account_object and save it:

```
@Override
    public StudentAccount save(StudentAccount studentAccount) {
        return studentAccountRepository.save(studentAccount);
    }

public void createStudentAccount(List<Student> studentsWithoutAccount) {
        for (int i=0; i<studentsWithoutAccount.size(); i++){
            String name = studentsWithoutAccount.get(i).getName();

            String username = name+"student";
            String password = username;

            StudentAccount studentAccount= new StudentAccount(username, password);
            save(studentAccount);

        }
    }
```

The save method in the repository that I use to save the object is the built-in save method from CrudRepository.
Should I write my own save method and insert the data in the relationship table manually?

Comment: If you have added a Student then that is what should happen. If it not working then add some more code such as how you construct and save the instance.

Comment: @AlanHay just edited the question. The Students are already in the database I just retrieve the students without an account and then just create the student account

Comment: I didn't read the whole question, and just stopped at the associations. Your mapping is incorrect. In a bidirectional association, the many side **must** be the inverse side, using the mappedBy attribute. Here's how you map a bidirectional OneToMany association: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional. Start by fixing that. Then, if you want a student to have an account, you must set its studentAccount property to a non null account.

Comment: Sorry, typo. The **one** side must be the inverse side.

Comment: @JBNizet changed it as you suggested now the relationship table is not being created automatically so I added the script to create the table from data.sql when I run the project and all students and students account get created there's no data being passed to the relationships table so it's empty

Comment: You probably changed the mapping to use a join column rather than a join table then. **If** you really want a join table, then you still need the JoinTable annotation, but **only** on the many side, since the one side is the inverse side of the accoaiation, and the mapping is thus already defined on the many side.

Comment: @JBNizet you are right. I thought so too. Relationship table now its created and filled with foreign keys. But its inserting keys that don´t even exist in the database i mean ids that don't exist. Weird

Comment: In the code you have posted you never associate a Student with the newly created account! `StudentAccount studentAccount= new StudentAccount(username, password);
            save(studentAccount);`

Comment: @AlanHay no i didn´t. I'm working on it right now. What i mentioned in the question is that i was filling up the database from a data.sql file in the templates folder. So there´s actually no call to `new StudentAccount` Seems that reading from a data.sql file doesn't create new objects and thus the wrong data was inserted in the database. But now it´s done the right way and it works as it should. I´ll be posting an answer soon. Thanks for the quick help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thanks to @JBNizet and @AlanHay for the support.

The problem was in the `@OneToMany` annotation, bad mapping. For a good source on how to do the mapping the right way go to [this link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional). As soon as I fixed the bad mapping the project worked, it was inserting the data automatically but with the wrong foreign keys.

This was the result of creating the database from a data.sql file in my project. What i did was to erase this file. I´m using spring boot web mvc so i erased the data.sql file from the **templates** folder and from **target/classes**.

Then i persisted the entities to the database the way it should be `Student student =new Student();` as well as `StudentAccount studentAccount = new StudentAccount();` and all that did the trick.

Here is the code:

**Student Class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "student_id")
    private int studentId;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<StudentAccount> studentAccounts;
```

**StudentAccount Class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student_account")
public class Users implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "student_account_id", nullable = false)
    private int studentAccountId;
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(name = "relationship_table",
            joinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_account_id"))
    private Student student;
```

**Implementation method:**

```
@Autowired
private StudentAccountRepository studentAccountRepository;
@Autowired
private StudentRepository studentRepository;
    public void createDatabase(){
            List<Student> students= new ArrayList<Student>();
            List<StudentAccount> studentAccounts= new ArrayList<StudentAccount>();

            Student student1  = new Student ("john");
            Student student2  = new Student ("david");
            Student student3  = new Student ("emma");
            Student student4  = new Student ("sophia");
            Student student5  = new Student ("mia");

            students.add(student1);
            students.add(student2);
            students.add(student3);
            students.add(student4);
            students.add(student5);

            studentRepository.saveAll(students);

            StudentAccount studentAccount1 = new StudentAccount("john", "john", student1);
            StudentAccount studentAccount2 = new StudentAccount("david", "david", student2);
            StudentAccount studentAccount3 = new StudentAccount("emma", "emma", student3);
            StudentAccount studentAccount4 = new StudentAccount("sophia", "sophia", student4);
            StudentAccount studentAccount5 = new StudentAccount("mia", "mia", student5);

            studentAccounts.add(studentAccount1);
            studentAccounts.add(studentAccount2);
            studentAccounts.add(studentAccount3);
            studentAccounts.add(studentAccount4);
            studentAccounts.add(studentAccount5);

            studentAccountRepository.saveAll(studentAccounts)
        }
**StudentRepository class:**

    @Repository
    public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, Integer> {

    }
**StudentAccountRepository class:**

    @Repository
    public interface StudentAccountRepository extends CrudRepository<StudentAccount, Integer> {
    }
```

And that's it. Thanks for the help!!